# Is "the sound of a good many voices" correct in this sentence and why?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, indefinite-article

From Alice in Wonderland:

> She waited for some time without hearing anything more: at last came a rumbling of little cartwheels, and the sound of **a good many voices** all talking together: she made out the words: 'Where's the other ladder?

Why did the writer add an article with the plural noun voices?

Answer (score 2):

**A good many** is a phrase.

[here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-good-many) is the definition.